# International friendly alternative icons to thumbs up/down

Tags: globalization

I am working on a website where I will be adding a "Pass/Fail" option for users to rate if they Approve of some things, similar to a Like/Dislike. I was originally thinking of using thumbs up/down for the website, but I am concerned about some of the international countries that may find this offensive.

Does anyone have any suggestions for icons that could represent "Pass" and "Fail" that would be internationally friendly?

Comment: Hi venom13. Unfortunately icon suggestions are off topic at UX.SE, as they tend to be too localized. Icons [do not improve usability](http://uxmyths.com/post/715009009/myth-icons-enhance-usability) and [understanding of an icon's meaning](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/) only exist through previous experience.

Comment: According the the "do not improve usability" link, "Where icons add value: Universally understood icons work well (ie. print, close, play/pause, reply)." I am looking for universally understood icons that are friendly and understood to most cultures.

Comment: Print, close, play/pause, reply are all icons that people have *learned* the meaning of through experience. There is no icon that people "just know" universally. There are several icon combinations that could be used, but they will always be open to interpretation by the user.

Answer (score 1):

A green checkmark (√) or a red X. [It's what Dropbox uses](https://www.dropbox.com/help/406).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @CharlesWesley He didn't ask for an explanation. He only asked for suggestions (which is the reason the question was put on hold and will most likely be closed). The link was merely auxiliary. I understand what you mean though, about information persistence and the value of having it included in the answer.